# Fastest way to drop rows / get subset with difference from large DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Question

I'm looking for the fastest way to drop a set of rows which indices I've got or get the subset of the difference of these indices (which results in the same dataset) from a large Pandas DataFrame.

So far I have two solutions, which seem relatively slow to me:

1. `df.loc[df.difference(indices)]`

   which takes ~115 sec on my dataset
2. `df.drop(indices)`

   which takes ~215 sec on my dataset

Is there a faster way to do this? Preferably in Pandas.

## Performance of proposed Solutions

- ~41 sec: `df[~df.index.isin(indices)]` [by @jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394627/3881681)

Comment: How working `df[~df.index.isin(indices)]` ?

Comment: uuuh nice :D 41 sec ^^. nice speed up so far.

Comment: @jezrael I agree that your solution is the fastest but one as to consider how many indices you want to remove. As example if `indices2remove` is bigger than `indices2keep` the `df[df.index.isin(indices2keep)]` it will be faster than `df[df.index.isin(indices2remove)]`

Comment: what is the amount of data you want to drop ? optimized algorithm can be found for asymptotic cases.

Comment: @jezrael Nope. Using `df.loc[]`  is 3x slower.

Comment: @B.M. between 2-8 Mio. of ~10Mio. rows.

Comment: @user32185 the amount/ratio I wanna drop varies (s. comment above). But I'll look into it.

Comment: @Ichixgo So given that a comparison of len shouldn't take long I'd suggest you to do so before drop indices.

Comment: @jezrael is there a possibility to contact you to discuss this again? I have a similar issue for my thesis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can create boolean mask, inverting by `~` and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[~df.index.isin(indices)]
```

As @user3471881 mentioned for avoid chained indexing if you are planning on manipulating the filtered `df` later is necessary add `copy`:

```
df1 = df[~df.index.isin(indices)].copy()
```

---

This filtering depends of number of matched indices and also by length of DataFrame.

So another possible solution is create `array/list` of indices for keeping and then inverting is not necessary:

```
df1 = df[df.index.isin(need_indices)]
```

Comment: Note that if you save this in a new variable you will have to `copy` the filtered `df`, if you are planning on manipulating the filtered `df`later. Don't know how this will effect performance but worth noting.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (or `loc`, see below) and [`Series.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 1000000, 1))
indices = np.arange(0, 1000000, 3)

%timeit -n 100 df[~df.index.isin(indices)]
%timeit -n 100 df.iloc[df.index.drop(indices)]

41.3 ms ± 997 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
32.7 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As @jezrael points out you can only use `iloc` if `index` is a [`RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.RangeIndex.html) otherwise you will have to use `loc`. But this is still faster than `df[df.isin()]` (see why below).

All three options on 10 million rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 10000000, 1))
indices = np.arange(0, 10000000, 3)

%timeit -n 10 df[~df.index.isin(indices)]
%timeit -n 10 df.iloc[df.index.drop(indices)]
%timeit -n 10 df.loc[df.index.drop(indices)]

4.98 s ± 76.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
752 ms ± 51.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2.65 s ± 69.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**Why does super slow `loc` outperform `boolean_indexing`?**

Well, the short answer is that it doesn't. `df.index.drop(indices)` is just a lot faster than `~df.index.isin(indices)` (given above data with 10 million rows):

```
%timeit -n 10 ~df.index.isin(indices)
%timeit -n 10 df.index.drop(indices)

4.55 s ± 129 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
388 ms ± 10.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

We can compare this to the performance of `boolean_indexing` vs `iloc` vs `loc`:

```
boolean_mask = ~df.index.isin(indices)
dropped_index = df.index.drop(indices)

%timeit -n 10 df[boolean_mask]
%timeit -n 10 df.iloc[dropped_index]
%timeit -n 10 df.loc[dropped_index]


489 ms ± 25.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
371 ms ± 10.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2.38 s ± 153 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: hmmm, iloc is possible use only for default RangeIndex, so not sure if possible use for OP solution.. :)

Comment: @user3471881 I'll check out your solution later.

Comment: added some extra context for why even `loc` outperforms `boolean_indexing` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If order of rows doesn't mind, you can arrange them in place :

```
n=10**7
df=pd.DataFrame(arange(4*n).reshape(n,4))
indices=np.unique(randint(0,n,size=n//2))

from numba import njit
@njit
def _dropfew(values,indices):
    k=len(values)-1
    for ind in indices[::-1]:
            values[ind]=values[k]
            k-=1

def dropfew(df,indices):
    _dropfew(df.values,indices)
    return df.iloc[:len(df)-len(indices)]
```

Runs :

```
In [39]: %time df.iloc[df.index.drop(indices)]
Wall time: 1.07 s

In [40]: %time dropfew(df,indices)
Wall time: 219 ms
```

Comment: upvoted for speed but OP asked for solutions using only `pandas` as far as I understood, this requires `numba` which should at least be mentioned explicitly. (not only by importing the module :D)

Comment: @user3471881: OP said preferably ;) . But that shuffle rows.